# Angular UI navbar collapse not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I can't seem to get my navbar to start as collapsed with the below code. I'm using Angular-ui-bootstrap:

navbar.directive.html:

```
<button type="button" ng-click="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed">
  <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>
<div collapse="isCollapsed">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Testing...</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

navbar.controller.js:

```
angular.module('gameApp')
  .controller('NavbarController', NavbarController);

NavbarController.$inject = ['playersService'];

function NavbarController(playersService) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.isCollapsed = true;

  var getCurrentPlayer = function() {
    playersService.getCurrentPlayer().$promise.then(function(data) {
      vm.player = data.player;
    });
  };

  var init = function() {
    getCurrentPlayer();
  };

  init();
}
```

When the page is minimized to the point where the responsive navbar toggle appears the menu is already showing. Even if I change it to `vm.isCollapsed = false;` the menu still starts as open.

Comment: Bingo, thanks! My directive uses `controllerAs: 'navbar'`, but my HTML is missing `navbar` in front of `isCollapsed`. Time to call it quits for the night, that was a bonheaded mistake haha.

Comment: I haven't injected a service like this but I usually set `$rootScope` as a dependency of my service, modify it, and (if isolated scope) set `$scope.x = $rootScope.x` in controller. I also haven't seen a controller using `this`, did you mean to inject `$scope` and set `$scope.vm.isCollapsed` and access `collapse="vm.isCollapsed"`?

Comment: @Plato no, you use `this` in controller when using `controllerAs` alias...then use that alias as prefix for all variables in view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Controller is built using `this` to allow `controllerAs` syntax but variables in html are set up to use `$scope`.

If directive does not have isolated scope you need to declare the alias for controller somewhere and prefix all the variables with the alias.

--OR--

Need to change controller to bind all the variables to $scope not `this`

Not sure how directive is configured or where controller is being declared in the view